# How to change the form (edit properties) in ALFRESCO?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I try to change a lots of file from Alfresco folder like : share-form-config,share-config at section:
< form id="doclib-simple-metadata" >

But no result.

Can someone explain me how to change this there or to create one new ?

I want to add field Email there for example..

Thx,

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a [custom share config](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/share-customize.html) so you can override the form or form fields for a given type?

Comment: Yes,if a press edit properties to a document I want to see there more fields like : mail,a checkbox for ex, not only Name,Title..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add form by editing below file in alfresco share

**share-config-custom.xml.**

Do not touch any other file. This file should be placed inside **{tomcat}\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension** folder.

For adding field in alfresco share form you should know below thing.

1.There is one condition attribute in config element of alfresco share form, which is used for evaluating condition.This can be based on aspect or type of node.

2.There is one another attribute called evaluator which is used for specifying that which kind of evaluator you are using whether it is aspect based,type based etc..

3.you will need to create content model for adding fields in alfresco.For more details on this please go to alfresco wiki.and look for content model.

Below is one simple example for alfresco share form.

```
<config condition="dms:emailTypeDoc" evaluator="node-type" replace="true">
        <forms>
            <form>
                <field-visibility>
                    <show force="false" id="dms:email" />
                </field-visibility>
                <appearance>
                    <field id="dms:email" label="E-Mail" mandatory="false"
                        read-only="false" />            
                </appearance>
            </form>
        </forms>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I understand what you said but I also have a little question which I don't know now and I need an example.

Comment: please describe it here.or post new question if description is too long

Comment: Thank you very much.I understand what you said but I also have a little question which I don't know now and I need an example.I want to see this form which you wrote in menu edit properties on a document .What I need to edit here to see there,thanks a lot.And I need to add in share-config-custom where you said ?

Comment: condition="dms:emailTypeDoc"   you need to change this things to your type of document.